# Memory not getting reclaimed on restart of a process

Tags: python, memory-management, gpu, caffe

I have a python job that runs a caffe net for image processing on nvidia GPUs. The job takes images from a rabbitmq queue, processes it and then writes the result in another queue. When I restart this job, the processes are getting killed but memory is not getting reclaimed.

So after certain number of restarts the machine crashes. Once I kill the job there is no python process running in ps or top but the CPU memory is not getting reclaimed.

How can I debug this issue?

EDIT: CPU memory

Comment: Are you referring to GPU memroy or CPU memory?

Comment: CPU memory. The one that you get from free.

Answer (score 2):

It's your GPU memory which is not getting freed. Get the process id

```
$ nvidia-smi
```

and then

```
$ kill -9 <process id>
```

Comment: I get "no process running" when I run nvidia-smi.

Comment: Can you see the process which is consuming the extra memory? Find out the process using ``$ ps aux | less``. Then kill the process with ``$ pkill -9 <process id>``.

Comment: No process is running in ps or htop. Looks like it is some bug in Caffe library which is not releasing shared memory.

Comment: I don't understand. When you say that the CPU memory is not getting reclaimed, it means there must be some process consuming the memory. You're definitely overlooking it. Run Caffe again and then check the memory used by different processes in CPU and GPU in a different terminal.