# GPU out of memory when neural network is called from python function

Tags: python, caffe

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40090892/check-failed-error-cudasuccess-2-vs-0-out-of-memory?noredirect=1#comment67488647_40090892) very recently: 
I want to use a caffe convolutional neural network in python for pixel-wise classification on an image sequence.
Previously, I determined the maximum image size that I can process with my gpu (450x450 pixels).
To process larger images, I want a nested loop like so:

```
function process_image_stack(image_stack, parameters):
    for all images
       take image apart into segments
       for all image_segments
           process image segment with network
           stitch together output
return processed_image_stack
```

My problem now is the following:
When I call net.forward() from a function like so:

```
output = processing_function(parameters)
```

CUDA throws an error that it is out of memory

```
Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (2 vs. 0) out of memory
```

I also get this error when I use a much smaller image as input

The problem seems to be the loop.
When I "manually" loop through the images, i.e. setting variables to 0,1,2... and then calling the net on the individual ones, it works fine.

I would like to understand what the problem actually is.

Thank you very much!

Comment: are all images of same size?

Comment: The image stack has images of the same size. When the individual images are cut into smaller segments, these segments may have unequal size. I accommodate this by using net.blobs['data'].reshape

Comment: are you freeing the memory after each iteration?

Comment: The only way to do that was to delete the net after processing the images. This was suggested to me in the previous question I asked. I do not know how to do free the memory without deleting the net.

Comment: "What about using a command del your_net to free the net object in python?" I commented there in the previous question.